# JAVA web service receiving null parameters from Android Ksoap

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to consume a JAVA web service from android.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
private void CallWebServiceDummy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();       

          StringArraySerializer a = new StringArraySerializer();
          a.add("hello"); a.add("world"); String n0 = NAMESPACE;

          pi = new PropertyInfo(); pi.setName("a"); pi.setValue(a);
          pi.setType(a.getClass()); pi.setNamespace(n0);
          Request.addProperty(pi);

          String b = "my name"; pi = new PropertyInfo(); pi.setName("b");
          pi.setValue(b); Request.addProperty(pi);


        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        Log.d("test", "request: " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        Log.d("test", "response: " + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;       

        String c = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), duration);
        toast.show();

        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

My Java web service Code:

```
package MyPackage;

public class WebServiceClass {

public String addnumbers(String[] a, String b) {
    String c = new StringBuilder("This the String1 ").append(a[0]).append(" merged with String2 ").append(b).toString();

    return c;
}
}
```

My Globals:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://MyPackage"; private
  static final String URL =
  "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebService/services/WebServiceClass?wsdl"; private
  static final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:addnumbers"; private static final
  String METHOD_NAME = "addnumbers";
```

Issue:

The response I receive is:

```
  addnumbersResponse{return=This the String1  merged with String2 my name; }
```

The first parameter is not being sent to web service. I have tried to remove this line:

soapEnvelope.dotNet = false; but its still not working.

Guys please help me out. I am stuck for two days. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your method's first argument's type is String array, not only String. Instead of `StringArraySerializer`, please try adding strings manually. You should see this page for this: [Adding an array of complex objects to the request](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request).

Comment: thanks for reply, but StringArraySerializer a = new StringArraySerializer();a.add("hello"); a.add("world"); is also creating an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your namespace is right!

I spent three hours with the same problem and only then realized that the namespace that was declared in the WebService class was different from what I put in the creation of SoapObject.